# Why does my <div> does not automatically set its height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have an HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="act">
  <div>/*left button*/</div>
  <div>
    <p>My very long text goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div>/*right button*/</div>
</div>
```

My outer div have a `min-height` but I don't set its `height` so that it fits whatever inside it. It looks just fine when that `<p>` has short text, but if I put a long text inside the `<p>`, the text overflows outside the outer `<p>`.

Here is my css (sass) file

```
@mixin flexCenter($direction) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: $direction;
}

.act {
  @include flexCenter(row);
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.48);
  padding: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1.35rem;
    height: 2.35rem;
    border-radius: 2px;
    @include flexCenter(row);
    &:nth-child(2) {
      background: inherit;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      p {
        font-size: .9rem;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't figure it out, maybe anyone could help me? Thank you

Comment: Hey, would like to help you but I didn't fully understand the problem. Could you create a code snipped (The <> button in the editor)?

Comment: thanks @webwelten i tried out adding `display: block; height: auto` and it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add this

```
display: block;
height: auto;
```

block of code inside the **:nth-child(2)** block 
as shown below

```
    &:nth-child(2) {
      background: inherit;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      height: auto;
      text-align: center;
      p {
        font-size: .9rem;
      }
    }
```